# Sample buffer in AVCaptureVideoDataOutput

Tags: ios, avfoundation, video-capture, avcapturesession

I'm thinking in an application that i want to take the `sampleBuffer` from a capture output and process it to become a stream broadcast on a web server I've been doing Goggling since two months and I've figured out a lot of things in `AVFoundation` such capturing sessions and the associated delegates

My Question is: Can I upload the sample buffer inside this delegate to a web Server and do processing on it, for example appending the samples to make a stream or a video file or even decode it

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
      Upload(sampleBuffer);
}
```

? Or do I need to do the processing inside the Objective-C Code and upload it to the web server decoded in certain codec and ready to be streamed?

Comment: you sloved this ?please post it as answer if you solved

Comment: sorry bro i didn't. I gave up ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I badly requires this for live video broadcasting from iphone to server